# Poner color botón formulario bootstrap 4

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-4

Hola que tal estoy construyendo un formulario con HTML5 y bootstrap, pero no consigo ponerle color al botón submit .
Quiero ponerle color negro (dark) con bootstrap.
Mucha gracias por su atención, felices fiestas decembrinas.

```
<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos/recibepedidos.php"  method="post">
            <fieldset>              
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label class="text-success" for="nom" >Nombre</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" name="nombre">        
                         </div>
</fieldset>
                                    
        <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-success" for="eda">Edad</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control" id="eda"  name="edad">   
                                    </div>
                                    
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-success" for="emai">Correo electronico</label>
                         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emai"  name="email">  
                                    </div>
</fieldset> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Enviar</button>` Estas aplicando solo el contorno negro y no el background

Answer (score 1):

Revisando las [opciones de botones](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/), el estilo debería ser `class="btn btn-dark"` para aplicar color de fondo y no de borde (outline) como estás haciendo ahora.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="regiration_form" action="procesamientos/recibepedidos.php"  method="post">
            <fieldset>              
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <label class="text-success" for="nom" >Nombre</label>
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nom" name="nombre">        
                         </div>
</fieldset>
                                    
        <fieldset>
                                                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-success" for="eda">Edad</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control" id="eda"  name="edad">   
                                    </div>
                                    
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <label class="text-success" for="emai">Correo electronico</label>
                         <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emai"  name="email">  
                                    </div>
</fieldset> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Enviar</button>
</form>
```